# How to split a string into list of characters and then concatenate by each character

Tags: python, split, concatenation

Is it possible to split a Python string every nth character and then concatenate the subsequent characters?

For example, suppose I have a string containing `'Coffee'`.

How can I split and get these variations:

```
C
Co
Cof
Coff
Coffe
Coffee
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, in Python 3.2+, [`itertools.accumulate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate("Coffee"))
['C', 'Co', 'Cof', 'Coff', 'Coffe', 'Coffee']
```

It's worth noting that this is probably not a particularly efficient method as it (internally) will use a lot of string concatenations, I provide it as a matter of interest, rather than being the best possible way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for loop:

```
>>> s = 'Coffee'

>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...     print s[:i+1]

C
Co
Cof
Coff
Coffe
Coffee
```

or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))]
['C', 'Co', 'Cof', 'Coff', 'Coffe', 'Coffee']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a couple of working solutions, no-one would crucify me for throwing a brain teaser in your face. Have fun with this one:

```
map(lambda x:x[::-1],re.findall(r"(?=(.+))","Coffee"[::-1]))[::-1]
```